# How to change the text colour in Latex within the environment \copyrightbox?

Tags: color

I would like to use the same text colour in my document. For some reason, the text within the \copyrightbox environment has a light grey text color and is not just black as in the text and table. How can I change the text colour within this environment?

```
\copyrightbox [b] {
\begin{tabular}{lllccrr}
\hline
\hline
dataset & test & Hypotheses & country-fixed effects & year-fixed effects & F statistic & p-value\\ 
\hline
lending & Chow-test & H0: pooling, H1: fixed effects & X & X & 44.42 & 2.2e-16\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}{source: own representation}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You have not posted any cod e related to color. Please post an example that we can run to see your problem. You have not even said how `\copyrightbox` is defined

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try `\copyrightbox{\color{black}\begin{tabular}…\end{tabular}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, with the help of the package documentation, and some improvements, with the `makecell, geometry & booktabs` packages, to avoid the table overflowing into the margin, also some vertical paddings around the horizontal rules and line breaks in the column headers:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
 \usepackage{copyrightbox}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
\footnotesize
\color{black}}
\makeatother
 \copyrightbox [b] {%
\begin{tabular}{lllccrr}
\toprule\midrule
dataset & test & Hypotheses & \makecell{country-fixed\\ effects} & \makecell{year-fixed\\ effects} & F statistic & p-value\\
\midrule
lending & Chow-test & \makecell[l]{H0: pooling,\\ H1: fixed effects} & X & X & 44.42 & 2.2e-16\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
{source: own representation}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, Bernard. Thank you!

Comment: @TiagoFernandes: You're welcome. Please note how the `makecell` package is useful to help having a table with ordinary specifiers fit between margins.